# How do I install homestead in windows 8

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem with installing homestead in windows 8, using vagrant.

I typed in like

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead` as well as

`composer require laravel/homestead --dev` to make sure that homestead files are installed properly.

also I added environmental variable where homestead.yaml is located.
as a result, I sucessfully access to homestead in cmd.

but when I typed in `homestead edit` it said,

> Windows can not find 'C:\USERS\PETER.homestead\Homestead.yaml' Make
>   sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

so, I checked the file location c:\users\peter.homestead\homestead.yaml, but the directory, .homestead, does not exist in PETER directory.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help or feedback will be appreciated.

Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `homestead init` for the folder to be generated. Navigate to the path and you should see it.